# Comparing Unequal Lists of Surnames to Establish Over or Under-Representation

Tags: list-manipulation, text

I've been using *Mathematica* to explore historical records. I have two long lists (one is 69k, the second 17k) of unequal length. They are like so (FWIW, the first list is the first 40 entries from the surnames of First World War attestation papers; the second list is the first 30 entries from the surnames of First World War war grave surnames - I have created percentage lists, to get a sense of how frequent their names were amongst all names):

```
atts={{"SMITH", 0.10031}, {"BROWN", 0.0555427}, {"WILSON", 
  0.0451438}, {"MCDONALD", 0.0411175}, {"JONES", 
  0.0375836}, {"TAYLOR", 0.0356139}, {"CAMPBELL", 
  0.033398}, {"JOHNSON", 0.0320656}, {"ANDERSON", 
  0.0303276}, {"WILLIAMS", 0.0298352}, {"THOMPSON", 
  0.0289952}, {"MARTIN", 0.0279669}, {"SCOTT", 0.0257944}, {"WHITE", 
  0.0250413}, {"STEWART", 0.0243606}, {"MILLER", 0.0240854}, {"CLARK",
   0.0237088}, {"MACDONALD", 0.0224054}, {"WALKER", 
  0.0216233}, {"JOHNSTON", 0.0212322}, {"MOORE", 0.0212177}, {"YOUNG",
   0.0211888}, {"ROBINSON", 0.0209426}, {"ROSS", 
  0.0196391}, {"WRIGHT", 0.018437}, {"MURRAY", 
  0.0182053}, {"ROBERTSON", 0.0181763}, {"MITCHELL", 
  0.0177273}, {"MCLEOD", 0.0176839}, {"JACKSON", 0.0175825}};    

kia={{"SMITH", 0.0452787}, {"BROWN", 0.0260468}, {"WILSON", 
      0.0195784}, {"JONES", 0.0174415}, {"TAYLOR", 
      0.0169217}, {"CAMPBELL", 0.0166907}, {"McDONALD", 
      0.0146694}, {"ANDERSON", 0.0127057}, {"JOHNSON", 
      0.012417}, {"STEWART", 0.0123592}, {"SCOTT", 0.0120705}, {"WHITE", 
      0.0118394}, {"WILLIAMS", 0.0116662}, {"THOMPSON", 
      0.0115507}, {"MARTIN", 0.0107421}, {"WALKER", 0.0106844}, {"MOORE", 
      0.0103956}, {"CLARK", 0.0102224}, {"YOUNG", 0.0101646}, {"MILLER", 
      0.0101646}, {"ROSS", 0.00987583}, {"ROBERTSON", 
      0.00981808}, {"REID", 0.00958706}, {"WRIGHT", 0.00918279}, {"KING", 
      0.00912504}, {"MURRAY", 0.00895178}, {"MITCHELL", 
      0.008432}, {"JOHNSTON", 0.00825874}, {"HALL", 
      0.00820098}, {"MORRISON", 0.00814323}};
```

Does *Mathematica* have a function that could help compare these two lists? I'm trying to think of a systematic way to establish that McDonald, for example, is under-represented in the war graves (4% of enlistees had the last name McDonald, whereas only 1.4% of dead did so). But since our lists are so long, would there be any way to do this systematically?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the names are unique in each list? (BTW, I'd suggest to use strings instead of symbols for the names)

Comment: @celtschk I've generated the list from getting a long list of names (some 650k of them) and then `Sort`ing and `Tally`ing, like so: `Sort[Sort[Tally[names[[All, 1]]]], #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]`. So they should be unique?

Comment: @celtschk And if I head the name, it's a string - I'm not 100% clear what you mean by symbols vs. strings.

Comment: Yes, that should ensure that the names are unique. BTW, I notice that the first list contains `MCDONALD` while the second list contains `McDONALD` (note the case difference of the `c`). Given that otherwise everything is in uppercase, I guess that's an error.

Comment: @celtschk Good catch - I've now put a `ToUpperCase` in my code that generated these lists. Thanks!

Comment: OK, so I get you didn't paste the `InputForm` here. You should do so because otherwise copy/pasting will generally (and especially in your case) result in a *different* list than the one you actually have. In your case, e.g. `{SMITH,0.0452787}` instead of `{"SMITH",0.0452787}` where the former `SMITH` parses as symbol (that is, as a name you can assign values to).

Comment: So are you looking for a comparison of the percentages?

Comment: @celtschk Changed above, is that better?

Comment: @DavidSlater That would be great - a list that had the difference in percentage that could then be played with. My issue so far has been the different length of lists.

Comment: Yes, now it should correctly parse to (the beginning of) your actual list.

Comment: BTW, you can replace your double `Sort` (from your first comment) by a single `Sort`: `Sort[Tally[names[[All, 1]] ], Which[#1[[2]] > #2[[2]], True, #2[[2]] > #1[[2]], False, True, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] ]&`

Comment: What stands out is that *all* the names appear under-represented in the `kia` list. The general trend appears to be roughly a factor of 1/2 between the two lists. I think any analysis will need to take this overall trend into account.

Comment: I agree with @Simon: there's something fishy about these two sets of data. They have essentially the same *relative* values, but the numbers in the second one are only about 45% of those in the first one (40-50% actually, but without having actual *counts* available it's impossible to tell whether this is random variation or something real).  It would appear just about *everybody* is "under-represented", but that does not seem possible (or informative).

Comment: @SimonWoods The example data used the wrong denominator in part of it (my bad), but I've double checked and the full sets do total out properly. Sorry - the ideas below are working quite well!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gathering together the unique names from both lists using `Union` and then selecting the cases for each name from the `atts` list and the `kia` list, we can then associated the name with the two relevant percentages and replace missing names with zero precentage.

```
With[{names = Union[atts[[All, 1]], kia[[All, 1]]]}, 
     {#, Cases[atts, {#, _}], Cases[kia, {#, _}]} 
     /. {{} -> 0, {{_, x_?NumericQ}} -> x} & 
     /@ names
    ]
```

Gives the following:

> {{ANDERSON, 0.0303276, 0.0127057}, {BELL, 0.0171914, 0}, {BROWN, 
>     0.0555427, 0.0260468}, {CAMPBELL, 0.033398, 0.0166907}, {CLARK, 
>     0.0237088, 0.0102224}, {DAVIS, 0.016728, 0}, {GRAHAM, 0.0172059, 
>     0}, {HALL, 0.016699, 0.00820098}, {HILL, 0.017148, 0}, {JACKSON, 
>     0.0175825, 0}, {JOHNSON, 0.0320656, 0.012417}, {JOHNSTON, 0.0212322,
>      0.00825874}, {JONES, 0.0375836, 0.0174415}, {KING, 0.0168149, 
>     0.00912504}, {MACDONALD, 0.0224054, 0}, {MARTIN, 0.0279669, 
>     0.0107421}, {McDONALD, 0, 0.0146694}, {MCDONALD, 0.0411175, 
>     0}, {MCLEAN, 0.0169452, 0}, {MCLEOD, 0.0176839, 0}, {MILLER, 
>     0.0240854, 0.0101646}, {MITCHELL, 0.0177273, 0.008432}, {MOORE, 
>     0.0212177, 0.0103956}, {MORRISON, 0, 0.00814323}, {MURRAY, 
>     0.0182053, 0.00895178}, {REID, 0.0173218, 0.00958706}, {ROBERTSON, 
>     0.0181763, 0.00981808}, {ROBINSON, 0.0209426, 0}, {ROSS, 0.0196391, 
>     0.00987583}, {SCOTT, 0.0257944, 0.0120705}, {SMITH, 0.10031, 
>     0.0452787}, {STEWART, 0.0243606, 0.0123592}, {TAYLOR, 0.0356139, 
>     0.0169217}, {THOMPSON, 0.0289952, 0.0115507}, {WALKER, 0.0216233, 
>     0.0106844}, {WATSON, 0.0174811, 0}, {WHITE, 0.0250413, 
>     0.0118394}, {WILLIAMS, 0.0298352, 0.0116662}, {WILSON, 0.0451438, 
>     0.0195784}, {WOOD, 0.0167859, 0}, {WRIGHT, 0.018437, 
>     0.00918279}, {YOUNG, 0.0211888, 0.0101646}}

Comment: This is better than the half finished answer I was working on.  Nice!

Comment: @DavidSlater diversity is a good thing, don't stop working :)

Answer (score 5):

@image_doctor 's solution gives you a nicely formatted data set with which you can then start looking at the differences.  For instance you can just compare the difference between the two percentages:

```
output = With[{names = Union[atts[[All, 1]], 
   kia[[All, 1]]]}, {#, Cases[atts, {#, _}], 
    Cases[kia, {#, _}]} /. {{} -> 0, {{_, x_?NumericQ}} -> x} & /@
  names];
output2 = Sort[{#[[1]], #[[2]] - #[[3]]} & /@ output, (#1[[2]] > #2[[2]]) &];


 BarChart[output2[[1 ;; 10, 2]], ChartStyle -> 20, 
          ChartLabels -> Placed[(output2[[1 ;; 10, 1]]), {{.75, 0}, {1, 1}},
          Rotate[#, Pi/3] &], BaseStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way, which keeps the order of `atts`, and the order of `kia` for the elements not in `atts` (which get collected at the end):

```
combine[a_, k_] :=
  Join[Append[#, First[Cases[k, {#[[1]], v_}:>v] /. {}->{0}]]& /@ a,
       {#[[1]], 0, #[[2]]}& /@ Select[k, FreeQ[a, #[[1]] ]&]]

all = combine[atts, kia]
(*
==> {{"SMITH", 0.10031, 0.0452787}, {"BROWN", 0.0555427, 0.0260468}, 
     {"WILSON", 0.0451438, 0.0195784}, {"MCDONALD", 0.0411175, 0}, 
     {"JONES", 0.0375836, 0.0174415}, {"TAYLOR", 0.0356139, 0.0169217}, 
     {"CAMPBELL", 0.033398, 0.0166907}, {"JOHNSON", 0.0320656, 0.012417}, 
     {"ANDERSON", 0.0303276, 0.0127057}, {"WILLIAMS", 0.0298352, 0.0116662}, 
     {"THOMPSON", 0.0289952, 0.0115507}, {"MARTIN", 0.0279669, 0.0107421}, 
     {"SCOTT", 0.0257944, 0.0120705}, {"WHITE", 0.0250413, 0.0118394}, 
     {"STEWART", 0.0243606, 0.0123592}, {"MILLER", 0.0240854, 0.0101646}, 
     {"CLARK", 0.0237088, 0.0102224}, {"MACDONALD", 0.0224054, 0}, 
     {"WALKER", 0.0216233, 0.0106844}, {"JOHNSTON", 0.0212322, 0.00825874}, 
     {"MOORE", 0.0212177, 0.0103956}, {"YOUNG", 0.0211888, 0.0101646}, 
     {"ROBINSON", 0.0209426, 0}, {"ROSS", 0.0196391, 0.00987583}, 
     {"WRIGHT", 0.018437, 0.00918279}, {"MURRAY", 0.0182053, 0.00895178}, 
     {"ROBERTSON", 0.0181763, 0.00981808}, {"MITCHELL", 0.0177273, 0.008432}, 
     {"MCLEOD", 0.0176839, 0}, {"JACKSON", 0.0175825, 0}, 
     {"McDONALD", 0, 0.0146694}, {"REID", 0, 0.00958706}, 
     {"KING", 0, 0.00912504}, {"HALL", 0, 0.00820098}, 
     {"MORRISON", 0, 0.00814323}}
*)
```

To get from this list all those underrepresented in the war graves, you can do

```
underrep = Select[all, #[[2]] > #[[3]]&]
(*
==> {{"SMITH", 0.10031, 0.0452787}, {"BROWN", 0.0555427, 0.0260468}, 
     {"WILSON", 0.0451438, 0.0195784}, {"MCDONALD", 0.0411175, 0}, 
     {"JONES", 0.0375836, 0.0174415}, {"TAYLOR", 0.0356139, 0.0169217}, 
     {"CAMPBELL", 0.033398, 0.0166907}, {"JOHNSON", 0.0320656, 0.012417}, 
     {"ANDERSON", 0.0303276, 0.0127057}, {"WILLIAMS", 0.0298352, 0.0116662}, 
     {"THOMPSON", 0.0289952, 0.0115507}, {"MARTIN", 0.0279669, 0.0107421}, 
     {"SCOTT", 0.0257944, 0.0120705}, {"WHITE", 0.0250413, 0.0118394}, 
     {"STEWART", 0.0243606, 0.0123592}, {"MILLER", 0.0240854, 0.0101646}, 
     {"CLARK", 0.0237088, 0.0102224}, {"MACDONALD", 0.0224054, 0}, 
     {"WALKER", 0.0216233, 0.0106844}, {"JOHNSTON", 0.0212322, 0.00825874}, 
     {"MOORE", 0.0212177, 0.0103956}, {"YOUNG", 0.0211888, 0.0101646}, 
     {"ROBINSON", 0.0209426, 0}, {"ROSS", 0.0196391, 0.00987583}, 
     {"WRIGHT", 0.018437, 0.00918279}, {"MURRAY", 0.0182053, 0.00895178}, 
     {"ROBERTSON", 0.0181763, 0.00981808}, {"MITCHELL", 0.0177273, 0.008432}, 
     {"MCLEOD", 0.0176839, 0}, {"JACKSON", 0.0175825, 0}}
*)
```

Or if you only want their names:

```
First /@ underrep
(*
==> {"SMITH", "BROWN", "WILSON", "MCDONALD", "JONES", "TAYLOR", "CAMPBELL", 
     "JOHNSON", "ANDERSON", "WILLIAMS", "THOMPSON", "MARTIN", "SCOTT", "WHITE", 
     "STEWART", "MILLER", "CLARK", "MACDONALD", "WALKER", "JOHNSTON", "MOORE", 
     "YOUNG", "ROBINSON", "ROSS", "WRIGHT", "MURRAY", "ROBERTSON", "MITCHELL", 
     "MCLEOD", "JACKSON"}
*)
```